# Hacer un salto de pagina cada vez que se aprieta enter

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

¡Hola! Bueno, tengo el siguiente codigo (supongo que no es necesario, pero por si acaso):

```
<div class="container-input">
            <h2 class="h2-input">Descripcion</h2>
            <p class="p-input">TEXTO</p>
            <textarea name="descripcion" id="" cols="15" rows="10" maxlength="600"><?php echo $descripcion ?></textarea>
        </div>
```

El textarea lo llevo a un php que hace un UPDATE, a esta descripcion se la coloca en la tabla "perfil_usuarios" en el atributo "descripcion", queria evitar poner el archivo, pero seguramente me digan que lo agregue:

```
$query_update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE perfil_usuarios SET lol = '$lol', discord = '$discord', descripcion = '$descripcion' WHERE username = '$usuario'");
    if ($query_update) {
    header("location:editar-perfil.php");
    }
```

De aqui, voy al perfil y coloco el siguiente codigo:

```
include("conexion.php");
        $perfil = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM perfil_usuarios WHERE username='$usuario'");
        $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($perfil);
        $descripcion = $row_user['descripcion'];

<div class="box w100">
            <h2 class="box-title">DESCRIPCION</h2>
            <h3 class="descripcion"><?php echo "$descripcion" ?></h3>
        </div>
```

Es, en efecto, una descripcion de un perfil.
Me gustaria que al presionar "enter" al estar escribiendo en el textarea, se haga un salto de pagina, con tal de que puedan dejar espacios de modo que se pueda hacer justamente lo que hice en este post, no quiero que cada vez que se aprete "enter", el input, aunque lo detecte, luego se imprima sin estos. Un ejemplo de lo que pasa:

Esto es una descripcion, aqui quiero hacer enter, lo presiono. Y aqui es luego de presionar enter.

Lo que quiero hacer es:

Esto es una descripcion, aqui quiero hacer enter, lo presiono.
Y aqui es luego de presionar enter.

Creo que es mucha informacion innecesaria, pero es para dejar en claro lo que quiero hacer.
No utilizo jquery ni otras librerias externas.
Supongo que esto se puede hacer con JS, pero no conozco mucho de este.

¡Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Comment: Donde guardas la información y como la recuperas. Por qué por defecto los saltos de línea se envían, no hay que hacer nada más. A la hora de pintar el texto en un documento html quizás debes pasarlo por la función nl2br y listo https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Sep, resuelto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, tome el codigo html en el que se imprimia esta descripcion y agregue "nl2br":

```
<h2 class="box-title">DESCRIPCION</h2>
            <h3 class="descripcion"><?php echo nl2br($descripcion) ?></h3>
```

Comment: En estos casos tambien puedes optar por usar CSS `.description {white-space: pre-wrap}` asi evitas hacer transformaciones de formato desde PHP con `nl2br()` y mantienes intacto el contenido

Comment: Genial, igual funciona a la perfeccion lo que me dio, pero si veo que tengo un problema supongo que utilizare eso